# Lebesgue measure using compact sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $m$ be the Lebesgue measure (defined via Carathéodory's approach). Show that
        $$m(E) = \sup\{m(K): K\subseteq E, \mbox{ compact}\}$$

The usual measure is defined
 $$m(E)=\inf\{\sum l(U_n): E \subseteq \cup U_n\}$$

and so it suffices to show that 
$$m(E) \leq \sup\{m(K): K\subseteq E, \mbox{ compact}\} \leq m(E)$$

It seems clear to me that 
$$\sup\{m(K): K\subseteq E, \mbox{ compact}\} \leq m(E)$$
and so the other inequality is all that needs to be proved. However, I am unsure of I would accomplish this as it seems this could (potentially) always force the measure of a set to be smaller than it ``actually'' is. What am I missing?

Comment: Sets cannot be summed. You wrote $\displaystyle m(E) = \text{inf} \left\{\sum U_n:E \subseteq \bigcup U_n \right\}$.

You probably need to take $m(U_n)$.

Comment: I suspect that this must have been asked somewhere here before. The property you are asking about is called "inner regularity".